# Выровнять центральный блок по центру

Tags: html, css

Как выровнять центральный блок по центру?

Что только не пробовал, ничего не выходит, центральный блок прижат к левому краю.

http://jsfiddle.net/rjqxt382/1/

Я уже не знаю, как его побороть.

Comment: [магия](http://jsfiddle.net/rjqxt382/2/) (обратите внимание на расположение блока `.next`)

Comment: [магия #2](http://jsfiddle.net/rjqxt382/3/) (text-align задается на уровне хедера и смещает inline-block)

Comment: @Etki не думал я, что всё так элементарно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте .title спаном http://jsfiddle.net/rjqxt382/4/